# How do I nest a declaration within another declaration?

Tags: formatting, nesting

I want to nest a bold-face formatting declaration within an italic-shape declaration. For that I tried using the command:

```
{\itshape\bfseries nested}
```

However, this doesn't work. Output given below:

[image: The word "nested" only appears in bold-face, but not italicized.]

The word "nested" only appears in bold-face, but not italicized.

Does anyone know how to nest a declaration within another declaration?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This depends on the font -- most likely your font does not support italic and bold simultaneously. With a standard document the nesting works. Please provide a minimal compilable document that has this issue and not a single line of code only

Comment: Not all fonts have bold italics.

Comment: presumably you get a warning in the terminal and the log file that bold italic is not available and LaTeX is substituting a different font.

Answer (score 5):

The default Computer Modern fonts don't have boldface slanted sans serif and you get informed about this by warnings such as

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 8.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 8.
```

The first warning tells you that LaTeX is trying a default substitution (slanted shape instead of italics), the second warning tells you that this substitution failed.

You have two strategies:

1. Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
2. Add `\usepackage{lmodern}`

The former will use the European Modern fonts, the latter the Latin Modern fonts.

In the following example, section 1 uses the default fonts in the OT1 encoding (no package); section 2 corresponds to adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; section 3 corresponds to adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`; section 4 corresponds to adding both packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Default CM (OT1)}

{\fontencoding{OT1}\sffamily\itshape\bfseries nested}

\section{Default EM (T1)}

{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries nested}

\section{Latin Modern (OT1)}

{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{lmss}\itshape\bfseries nested}

\section{Latin Modern (T1)}

{\fontfamily{lmss}\itshape\bfseries nested}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to be clearer, in order to follow strategy 1 you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries nested}

\end{document}
```

In order to follow strategy 2 you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries nested}

\end{document}
```